# Some columns empty in updated gridview row after update

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an ASPX page defined with a GridView control bound (via DataSourceID) to a sql database through an entity class.  After editing a row, the data is properly updated but some of the columns in the edited Row are now empty.  The columns that not empty show the updated data, and the data is in fact updated in the database.  Also, even the column that are shown empty in the updated row, are properly updated in the database.  The fact that the columns that are not empty show the updated data also proves that the GridView does a databind after row update.  Why some of the columns in the updated row show empty is beyond me...

What's more is that if I edit another row, the newly edited row now shows the same columns as empty that the previously edited row showed empty.  Then the previously edited row now shows all columns.

EDIT:
I just found out that this problem occurs only when I set **deferredloadingenabled** to true on the datasource.  It is happening for those columns that are not part of the entity table in the datasource.  I could fix this problem by creating a view but that is really inefficient.  That would mean I'd need to create a view for each gridview.

Comment: Are you just saying it would be inefficient because you want to be lazy and *not* make a view for each *gridview*? Or is there real evidence that shows it actually is not efficient?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that after the Update, links to other entities are NULL for the updated row.  What you can do is use the ID that corresponds to the link to the other entity and do an on-demand look-up.

That is, maybe your  is defined like <%# Eval("Customer.FirstName") %>, after the update, that row might be empty because the attribute "Customer" that is the link to the customer entity to get the first name, is null.  So just define the  like so:

```
<%# Eval("Customer.FirstName") ?? Customer.GetFirstNameByID(Eval("CustomerID")) %>
```

You would define the function GetFirstNameByID inside the Customer entity class to return the customer first name.  Now after an update, if and when the "Customer" attribute is null, the first Eval() will return null so the second statement will execute.  Eval("CustomerID") will work because the attribute "CustomerID" is a part of the current entity.  The proper attribute is then returned and the column does not appear null.